# SQL Server Sum data between two dates group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in my table:

```
eb          |anz
05.03.2020  | 2
06.03.2020  | 3
07.03.2020  | 1
08.03.2020  | 9
09.03.2020  | 10
10.03.2020  | 2
11.03.2020  | 20
12.03.2020  | 25
```

Now I need to sum the values in specific range for each date.
For example "12.03.2020": I want to sum the value of the 12th, 11th, 10th and 9th of march for the date "12.03.2020". Additionally I want to sum the other four values before 9th of march and divide the summary 1 by summary 2 by select.

So my calculation would be: (25+20+2+10)/(9+1+3+2) = 3.8
I would like to output the date and the calculated value for each date in table.

I tried to sum the first group for each date (in example 9th to 12th march) but the output is the same as the data in the table.

```
select
eb,
sum(anz)
from (select eb, count(*) as anz from myTable where eb != '' group by eb) tmp
where 
convert(date, eb, 104) >= dateadd(day,-3,convert(datetime, eb, 104)) 
and convert(date, eb, 104) <= convert(date, eb, 104)
group by eb
order by convert(date, eb, 104)
```

It looks like the condition is being ignored. Do you have any advice for me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have no column called `eb` in your table, so the query is not consistent with the question.

Comment: I edited it, sorry. Should be right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that `data` is stored correctly as a `date` then  you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(anz) over (order by eb rows between 3 preceding and current row) /
        sum(anz) over (order by eb rows between 8 preceding and 4 preceding)
       )
from t;
```

Note that if `value` is an integer, then use `* 1.0 /` to avoid integer division.

Also, this assumes that you have data on each date.